# CSS Drop Down Menu Remove border side

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop down menu like below but can't seem to get the border to appear around the menu, I would get rid of the border below 'Menu'

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not use outline for borders, because it does not support `outline-bottom`, which you would need, and is overall not cross-browser friendly.  http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/outline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was playing a lot with styles, so review it to understand.

First of all I've changed using `outline` to `borders`.
The main idea that `Menu` item doesn't have bottom border and it appears over the drop-down menu.

Here is working sample (FF6, IE9, Chrome tested): http://jsfiddle.net/a3MLn/9/

Comment: Thank you for your help, that looks great on Chrome & Safari (Mac) but i still see the border-bottom with firefox 6.0.2 osx lion, don't know why?

Also the reason I was using outline because when i have more items, the menu moves with borders set.

Comment: play with styles to overlap the top border of sub-menu with main `Menu` item. Maybe you will need to use css hacks or review positioning of the elements (for example replace `top:98%` with fixed size in pixels).